# Spacemacs test runner

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, cider

How can I get the Spacemacs test runner to work? It doesn't fail to run according to the messages buffer. It simply doesn't show the test report buffer and I have no idea what command to use to get it to show. I thought it was hidden in my buffers list but alas it is not there.

I am using Fedora release 30 (Thirty) running GNU Emacs 26.2 installed via dnf.

Comment: I never figured this out. I got my Mac back from repairs, re-configured Spacemacs and it just worked. I don't have Fedora anymore so I can't test it again.